# Disable button without javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, button, disabled-input

I am currently referring to my Wordpress login page (wp-login.php). I want the "Log In" button to be disabled by default without javascript and without the need to modify the core file. Meaning that the button will be disabled if the user did not run javascript on his browser. However, I tried looking for solution only but I guess the only thing that I can to do is to modify the core file by adding "disabled" attribute to the button.

Or is there any alternatives to "setAttribute" for the button without javascript?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Reference: http://www.codediesel.com/javascript/prevent-form-submissions-with-javascript-disabled/

Comment: Not a wise idea to modify WordPress core files.

Answer (score 1):

just add these properties to your btn class may it work

```
cursor: not-allowed;
pointer-events: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

ON pressing F5 page is reloaded. You need to reset all of your controls and the buttons and make

```
disabled=true
```

once loading is done.